# android:onClick attribute stopped working, can't find method in activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have bunch of buttons like this

```
<cz.applmartin.quicksketch.Gui.Buttons.CopyDragableImageButton
android:id="@+id/b_settings"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="b_settings"
android:background="@drawable/s_settings"
/>
```

And in activity coresponding methods like this

```
public void b_settings(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.getInstance(), SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

All methods exist and are public. Everythig seems ok. And I worked fine long time. Than it suddenly started to give this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method b_settings(View) in the activity class cz.applmartin.quicksketch.Main for onClick handler on view class cz.applmartin.quicksketch.Gui.Buttons.CopyDragableImageButton with id 'b_settings'
```

But I am sure that method is actualy present in Main and is public and with correct signature. Bug is showing only on devices and emulator with older apis. (tested 2.2 2.3)
On new apis (4.*) everything works fine.
As far as I know I didnt changed anything regarding xml with buttons or corresponding method in activity. It just stopped working for no obvious reason.

In manifest min sdk is 8 and target is 10. Build target in properties is 4.2

Did this happen to anyone before? Any clues? thanks

Answer (score 0):

i thought u took same project with another project. but u r using in layout as

Comment: Sorry I dont undersand you. Can you please try to explain your idea better? Thanks.

Comment: if your project package name is not same with cz.applmartin.quicksketch.Gui. then it will give error

Comment: project package name is cz.applmartin.quicksketch. But it is hardly an issue becouse it was the same before and it worked.